# Where can I find a discarded email draft in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I just pressed the <kbd>discard</kbd> button on a long email draft I was editing. Where can I find it now? I tried to search in the bin folder, but it's not there...

Comment: Try looking in the `draft` folder

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra, it disappeared from the `draft` folder after I pressed the discard button (by mistake obviously).

Comment: Then it's out of our hands. Now you need to focus on what you wanted to write....=)

Comment: and have a form recovery tool like Lazarus :) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lazarus-form-recovery/loljledaigphbcpfhfmgopdkppkifgno?hl=en

Comment: @Sathya - Yes, but Lazarus works in Chrome on PC, while, I have accidentally deleted a draft on an Android phone, in Gmail App. Isn't any tool to recover it? I mean, by connecting the phone to the computer?

Comment: @CristianaNicolae if it's composed on the phone, and you deleted then no, it's gone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As soon as you've (accidentally) hit the `discard` button you have the option to `undo discard` in the alert that appears at the top of the page. **Click that!** Or hit <kbd>z</kbd> (undo last action) if you have keyboard shortcuts enabled.

[image: Your message has been discarded. Undo discard]

However, as soon as you start to navigate around Gmail this alert disappears and your draft is gone for good it seems. (The keyboard shortcut <kbd>z</kbd> no longer works either.)

Comment: Yeah, it seems that way. Shame really, they could keep it in Trash for a few days.

Comment: super annoying!  There should be a confirmation, or a way to reverse it...one or the other!

Comment: This question has had 30,000 views in a year. You might expect that the alleged geniuses at Google could figure out that they are not doing it right, but they probably think they know what's best.

Comment: I had pressed "discard" on a draft on Gmail for iOS, not focused 100% clearly, thinking I was discarding my current edit, not the entire draft. Now it's gone gone gone. I didn't see a momentary undo option in this app, so it's gone for good. Hear our cry, Google/Gmail!

Comment: @TPoy You're right. On iOS/iPad, when closing an email you are editing ("draft" or "new" email) you get the option to "Discard" or "Save". Tapping "Discard" immediately discards that email with no option to "Undo". If this was a "new" email then there is no message at all, however, if it was a "draft" email I see a message at the bottom... "Your draft has been discarded x" (not "undo" option). You can't _close it without saving_. Only when "deleting" (trash icon) emails (inc. drafts) do you get the option to "Undo" (message at the bottom of the screen).

Answer (score 6):

You can't find it. Once you click that `discard` button it is gone. Gmail doesn't even move it to Trash.