# How do I retrieve a recently deleted item from Gmail?

Tags: gmail

While writing an answer to an email it went into draft mode and I deleted the draft while at the same time it deleted her email. How do I undo that? I was under the impression that deleted items stay in the trash bin and are available to be undone.

Answer (score 1):

To see what is in the trash search for:

in:trash

That will show you all the messages in trash. Open the message and remove the trash label.

I think that deleted drafts are gone forever.

Answer (score 0):

Drafts are deleted permanently immediately, only received and sent files are sent to trash.

Related

- [Where can I find a discarded email draft in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/43449/88163)
- [How to recover Gmail draft](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/88935/88163)