# Recovery of Discarded Draft

Tags: gmail

Suddenly in discarded, all of my Drafts... Is it possible to recover them somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find a discarded email draft in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43449/where-can-i-find-a-discarded-email-draft-in-gmail)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to recover them. Discarded drafts are deleted without being "saved" in Trash for further deletion.

[image: 0]